# add product to cocart woocomerce using rest api,and authenticatrion

Tags: flutter, dart, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

is it possible to add product to cart with cocart using consumer key and secret as authentication in restapi. as of  now im using customer password and email as authentication to add item to cart but i cant store email and password in local storage.
here is the link to documentation
https://docs.cocart.xyz/#add-to-cart-clear-cart-properties
any one knows please help

```
https://docs.cocart.xyz/#add-to-cart-clear-cart-properties

Future<List<CartItem>> AddToCart(
{required String? prodductid,
String? quantity = '1',
required String userid,
required String username,
required String password}) async {
 print("Adding to Cart");
 List<CartItem> cartItems = [];
// String username = 'basiltalks85@gmail.com';
// String password = 'basil51951';
//lets encode creds
 String basicAuth =
    'Basic ' + 
 base64Encode(utf8.encode('$consumerKey:$consumerSecret'));
print(basicAuth);

try {
  var response = await Dio().post(
    'https://beta.nilgiris.ae/wp-json/cocart/v2/cart/add-item? 
  cart_key=$userid',
    options: Options(
      headers: <String, String>{'authorization': basicAuth},
    ),
    data: {
      "id": prodductid,
      "quantity": quantity,
    },
  );
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print('on success add to cart');
    print(response);
    final res = response.data as Map<dynamic, dynamic>;
    final items = res['items'] as List;
    if (items.isEmpty) {
      return cartItems;
    }
    if (items.isNotEmpty) {
      for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        cartItems.add(CartItem.fromJson(items[i]));
      }
      return cartItems;
      }
    }
  } on DioError catch (e) {
    toast('Something Wrong');
  
    throw e;
  } catch (e) {
 
  throw e;
}
return cartItems;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

So if you install the Co-Cart JWT plugin, and configure it properly, by adding a COCART JWT KEY in your wp-config file.

Then if you check the cocart docs, there is an endpoint for login, when you use it, with your username and password. You will receive a jwt token in the response body. And then subsequently you pass that token for all other endpoints.

I am currently building a flutter app with a WP/WOO Rest backend. I know how tasking it is. Hope this helps